# Optimización de consulta case Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, subconsultas, usecase

Tengo una consulta en Sql Oracle Developer que me jala bien cuando la consulto sola pero cuando la ocupo en mi procedimiento almacenado se tarda mas de 5 min en ejecutarse, note que cuando le pongo la X para diferenciar tablas se alenta pero si se la quito realiza el proceso rápido pero no me realiza la diferencia en case de 1 y 0.

Donde deje las comillas van los parametros. Me podrian ayudar a porque me pasa esto y si hay alguna forma de optimizar la consulta.De antemano gracias.

También la realice con decode pero sigue realizándose de manera muy lenta.

```
 ,(   select  decode(count(*),0,'0','1') from fst135_invesdocumentos x1 where x1.fst136_idexpediente = fst136_guiasinvesdoc.fst136_idexpediente)

PROCEDURE Sp_ConsultaGuias( pstr_Master VARCHAR2, pstr_House VARCHAR2, pstr_Registro VARCHAR2, pstr_Fecha1 VARCHAR2, pstr_Fecha2 VARCHAR2, saldatos_cursor  OUT datos_cursor)
 IS
    lstrDescripcionErr   VARCHAR2(250);
    lstrCodeDescErr      VARCHAR2(45);
   sal_cursor datos_cursor;   
   fechaActual DATE;
 BEGIN
    
    SELECT sysdate INTO fechaActual from dual;
 
    OPEN sal_cursor FOR
          
        SELECT x.fst136_idexpediente, 
           x.fst136_nametipoexpediente, 
           x.fst136_gmaster, 
           x.fst136_ghouse, 
           x.fst136_registro, 
           to_char(x.fst136_fecharegistro,'DD/MM/YYYY') fst136_fecharegistro ,  to_char(x.fst136_fechaguardado,'DD/MM/YYYY') fst136_fechaguardado,  to_char(x.fst136_fechaentrada,'DD/MM/YYYY') fst136_fechaentrada
           ,(      SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>0
                             THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 
                END  columna FROM fst135_invesdocumentos x1 WHERE x1.fst136_idexpediente = x.fst136_idexpediente)
           AS estatus
           FROM fst136_guiasinvesdoc x
           WHERE 
           x.fst136_gmaster =  NVL('', fst136_gmaster) AND 
           x.fst136_ghouse = NVL('', fst136_ghouse) 
           AND  x.fst136_registro = NVL('', fst136_registro) 
           OR to_char(x.fst136_fechacreacion,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2023-01-02' AND to_char(x.fst136_fechacreacion,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2023-01-02';

    saldatos_cursor := sal_cursor; 



END Sp_ConsultaGuias;
```

Comment: No es necesario hacer `count(*)` basta con `exists()`: `, exists( SELECT 1 FROM st135_invesdocumentos x1 WHERE ... ) AS status`. ¿Qué índices tienes sobre documentos?

Comment: mi indice es fst136_idexpediente que comparte con la tabla de guiasdocumento, pero justo este x.fst136_idexpediente es lo que alenta la consulta igual quite el * y sigue tardando 3 min en el stored si lo manejo en query solo segundos

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta un `EXPLAIN` de la consulta.

Comment: como no entiendo ?